# Orchard get Taxonomy term name of a particular Content Item

Tags: orchardcms, taxonomy

Is it possible to get the taxonomy term name of a content item in orchard?
I use the Designer tools module and i cannot find it in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved, 'Category' is the name of my taxonomy:

```
   @{
    var categoryName = "";
    foreach (dynamic term in Model.ContentItem.BlogPost.Category.Terms.Value)
    {
        categoryName = term.Name;
    }
}
```